# Is the expression "guide insertion of paper " grammatically correct?

Tags: verbs

> 1. This attachment guides insertion of paper into a printer.
> 2. This tool guides insertion of a thread through a needle hole.

I cannot find this type of usage of "guide" in dictionaries, but can find it on the internet.  Is this usage correct?

Comment: What dictionaries did you consult to find the meaning and usage of the verb _guide_? I find it defined in dozens of them. Note also that in technical manuals (which are often written by non-English speakers) the articles are often omitted. The first sentence should be interpreted as _"This attachment guides **the** insertion of paper..."_

Comment: I consulted a lot of dictionaries including Longman, Collins, and Oxford.  They show that "guide" has the meaning of helping someone or something to move in a particular direction.  So, I think paper can be guided, but insertion cannot be guided.

Comment: Why do you think insertion can't be guided?  It's a noun (just like *paper* is) and means "the act of inserting something".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to understand that a *correct* usage is any usage that can be understood by most native English speakers. In the case of your examples, both would be easily understood, and that makes them "correct"!

The examples and definitions provided in a dictionary are not meant to be *exclusive*. The usages provided are not the *only* usages. The examples are provided as hints to present the ways in which a given word can be used. In the case of the transitive sense of the verb *guide*, the definition in the **[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guide)** dictionary is:

> 1. to act as a guide to :  direct in a way or course • He *guided* us around the city.
> 2. a. :  to direct, supervise, or influence usually to a particular end • You'll need a lawyer to *guide* you through the legal system.
>      b. :  to superintend the training or instruction of • A respected educator *guided* his studies.

To *guide*, then, means to *direct* in a purposeful way. We say:

> *guide* a thread through the eye of a needle

...but we could also say that we

> *guide the **insertion*** of the thread into the eye of the needle.

One of the examples in the M-W entry is:

> He claims that there were unknown forces ***guiding* the outcome** of the election.

Compare this with your first example:

> This attachment **guides [the] insertion** of paper into a printer.

Here, *guide* means *direct*:

> This attachment **directs [the] insertion** of paper into a printer.

Always consult multiple dictionaries and read multiple example sentences when you are learning a new word in English. We recommend the **[OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=guide&ls=a)** aggregator as a good place to start.